# Is using Timeline for scheduling correct

Tags: javafx, timer

I've found a lot of suggestions to use `Timeline` with `KeyFrame.onFinished` to schedule tasks in the *JavaFX*. But the `AnimationTimer` doc says, that its `handle` method is called 60 times per second.

It is unclear from documentation but it seems that `Timeline` uses `AnimationTimer` internally. Does that means that the timeline solution for scheduling imposes CPU-intensive polling mode? If that is actually how JavaFX works, what other methods for scheduling is recommended?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Advised Usage Rules for Scheduling in JavaFX**

Given how [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) works (see below), some basic rules can be derived:

1. *Use a Timeline* when you want to schedule quick operations that modify attributes of the scene graph.
2. *Do not use a Timeline* when you want to do any of the following:

   1. Perform operations that are themselves time-consuming (e.g. the work for a given scheduled activity takes longer than 1/30th of a second).
   2. Perform work which really doesn't have anything to do with the scene graph.
   3. Have real-time scheduling at a resolution greater than a pulse (1/60th of a second).
   4. Control your scheduling using traditional java.util.concurrent mechanisms or a third party library.
   5. Run your scheduled tasks on their own threads.

Also, for a one-off execution that updates the scene graph after a fixed delay, I like to use a [PauseTransition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34788728/1155209).

**Answers to specific questions and concerns**

> It is unclear from documentation but it seems that Timeline uses AnimationTimer internally.

No, [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) does not use [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) internally.  However, Timeline is still pulse based and will receive code to update the current state of the timeline will be invoked on each pulse (usually 60 times a second).  To understand what a pulse is read the background section below.

> Does that means that the timeline solution for scheduling imposes CPU-intensive polling mode?

Yes, there is some overhead, but it is likely minimal enough that it can be disregarded.  The JavaFX system is going to be running some work on each pulse anyway, regardless whether you create any timelines yourself.  Unless you are heavily animating objects or doing a lot of work on each pulse, then the time to process each pulse will be completely trivial as there is simply very little work to be done on each pulse.

> If that is actually how JavaFX works, what other methods for scheduling is recommended?

There are numerous alternatives to Timeline:

1. Use a [javafx.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html) facility such as a Task or Service, and specifically a [ScheduledService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html).

   - This is good if you want to provide feedback (such as progress, message updates and return values) to the JavaFX UI.
2. Use a [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) facility.

   - This is good if you don't need the additional features of javafx.concurrent for progress and messaging or if you want the additional control provided by java.util.concurrent facilities.
   - If you use this, you can still get intermittent or final feedback to your JavaFX UI by invoking [Platform.runLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).
3. Use a [java.util.TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

   - Simpler API than java.util.concurrent, no direct interface for JavaFX feedback, though again you can use Platform.runLater() for that.
4. Use a third party scheduling system (such as [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org)):

   - More complicated than other solutions, but also more flexible, though it adds a dependent library and requires Platform.runLater if you want to modify scene graph elements.

If you do use something other than a timeline, you need to take care:

1. You invoke Platform.runLater if you want to modify anything on the scene graph from your non-JavaFX application threads.
2. You don't invoke Platform.runLater too often so as to overload the JavaFX application thread (e.g. by [coalescing update calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020573/javafx-two-bound-properties-for-task)).

**Background Info**

*Timeline Operation*

For example, let's say you have a Timeline which has a [Keyframe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html) that has a duration of 1 second.  The internal Timeline will still be updated each pulse.  This is required because a Timeline is more than just a scheduler, it has other properties and tasks.  For instance the Timeline has a [currentTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#currentTimeProperty) property.  The currentTime will be updated each pulse, so that it always reflects the current time accurately.  Similarly, internal logic with the Timeline will check to see if there are any [KeyValues](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyValue.html) associated with the Timeline, and update their values on each pulse, in accordance with their associated [Interpolator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Interpolator.html).  And the internal logic will check on each pulse to see if the Timeline is finished, to call the onFinished handler.   It will also evaluate the current time versus the duration of each keyframe and, if there is a match, fire the appropriate action event for the keyframe.

So the Timeline is acting like a scheduler in that it can execute key frames at specific times, but it is more than a scheduler as it also maintains it's current time, current state and ability to continuously vary associated key values.  Additionally, you can vary the rate, direction and number of cycles of a timeline, as well as pause it in position, then resume it, which also differs from a traditional scheduler.

An aspect of the Timeline is that because it is based upon callbacks from pulses in the JavaFX system; everything runs on the JavaFX application thread.  Therefore, when you use timelines (even 1000 of them), no additional threads are spawned, so from that perspective it is lightweight.  Also all logic invoked by the timeline occurs on the JavaFX application thread.  Because everything runs on the JavaFX application thread, this makes the Timeline nice for manipulating elements and attributes of the active JavaFX scene graph (such manipulations must be performed on the JavaFX application thread).  However, a timeline would be a bad choice if you wanted to do a lot of CPU time-consuming work or blocking I/O in the associated timeline keyframes.  This is because the JavaFX application thread will be blocked while that work occurs, freezing your UI.

*Pulses*

The JavaFX runtime system is based upon [pulses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1106308).

> A pulse is an event that indicates to the JavaFX scene graph that it is time to synchronize the state of the elements on the scene graph with Prism. A pulse is throttled at 60 frames per second (fps) maximum and is fired whenever animations are running on the scene graph. Even when animation is not running, a pulse is scheduled when something in the scene graph is changed. For example, if a position of a button is changed, a pulse is scheduled.
>
> When a pulse is fired, the state of the elements on the scene graph is synchronized down to the rendering layer. A pulse enables application developers a way to handle events asynchronously. This important feature allows the system to batch and execute events on the pulse.

The JavaFX animation system stores a list of all of the [animations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html) and [animation timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) which been created and not garbage collected.  On each pulse it will iterate through this list.  Each animation timer will have it's [handle callback](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html#handle-long-) invoked on each pulse.  Each timeline or transition will similarly have its internal state update and update any associated key values or fire key frame action events as appropriate.

Comment: 2.4 & 2.5 bullets could be read as "do not use a timeline when your are not using it". Pulses are extremely heavy weight from your descriptions (when where are no other animation to share overhead with). So the ScheduledService seems most apropriate

Comment: Well, any of 2.1 to 2.5 are reasons not to use a Timeline.  There may well be others I didn't list.  Timelines have their place, it just depends upon what you are doing.  I don't think pulses are heavyweight (I didn't mean to give that impression).  Anyway, pulses will occur regardless of what you do, because the JavaFX architecture is pulse based.  ScheduledService is most appropriate for a lot of things, again, it just depends upon what you are doing.

Comment: 2.1 to 2.3 describes use cases where the `Timeline` is inappropriate. 2.4 & 2.5 describes technologies alternative to the `Timeline`. There are no pulses when there are no animations. So, plain javafx application rarely emits pulses. But once you added PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(10)) the application begun to emit pulses 60 times per second.

Comment: I don't know that that there "are no pulses when there are no animations".  I guess the JavaFX source code could to be studied in detail to determine that or perhaps you determined it through some other means.  For 2.4 and 2.5, I just meant don't use a Timeline when you want or need to use one of these alternatives (for whatever reason).  I guess it could have been worded better, but hopefully the gist of the advice is clear.

Comment: > when animation is not running, a pulse is scheduled when something in the scene graph is changed
So, when there is no animation the javafx system emits no pulses. Until something on the scene changes, but that occurs not so often

Comment: lol, I should read what I copy and paste, thanks for pointing this out ayvango.

Comment: I feel like this is a subtle question with an appropriately-subtle answer.

But a pulse occurring 60 times a second is by far NOT pure CPU polling.  A typical CPU has 16 million clock cycles in a period of 1/60 second, and only a tiny fraction of these will be used to monitor a CPU pulse when no actual animation work needs to be done.

We don't need to worry about overloading the CPU of anything running JavaFX in the foreground by turning on a Timeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

```
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Code goes here
    }
}
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Of course I can. Old good java is still accessible in any javafx application. That solution is well tested in bunch of different projects as core java. But requires a little of additional work to make interaction with javafx threadsafe. If all pure javafx solutions would be proven to burden CPU `ScheduledExecutorService` is the next obvious choice.